# Using dictionary to add some columns to a dataframe with assign function

Tags: python, pandas, list, lambda

I was using python and pandas to do some statistical analysis on data and at some point I needed to add some new columns with assign function

```
df_res = (
    df
    .assign(col1 = lambda x: np.where(x['event'].str.contains('regex1'),1,0))
    .assign(col2 = lambda x: np.where(x['event'].str.contains('regex2'),1,0))
    .assign(mycol = lambda x: np.where(x['event'].str.contains('regex3'),1,0))
    .assign(newcol = lambda x: np.where(x['event'].str.contains('regex4'),1,0))
)
```

I wanted to know if there is any way to add columns names and my regex to a dictionary and use a for loop or another lambda expression to assign these columns automatically:

```
Dic = {'col1':'regex1','col2':'regex2','mycol':'regex3','newcol':'regex4'}

df_res = (
    df
    .assign(...using Dic here...)
)
```

I need to add more columns later and I think it will make it easier to add new columns later.

Comment: for k,v in Dic.items(): df[k] = df['event'].str.contains(v).astype(int) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html

> Assigning multiple columns within the same assign is possible. For Python 3.6 and above, later items in ‘**kwargs’ may refer to newly created or modified columns in ‘df’; items are computed and assigned into ‘df’ in order. For Python 3.5 and below, the order of keyword arguments is not specified, you cannot refer to newly created or modified columns. All items are computed first, and then assigned in alphabetical order.
>   Changed in version 0.23.0: Keyword argument order is maintained for Python 3.6 and later.

If you map all your regex so that each dictionary value holds a lambda instead of just the regex, you can simply unpack the dic into assign:

```
lambda_dict = {
    col:
    lambda x, regex=regex: (
        x['event'].
        str.contains(regex)
        .astype(int)
    ) 
    for col, regex in Dic.items()
}
res = df.assign(**lambda_dict)
```

**EDIT**
Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(0)
events = ['apple_one', 'chicken_one', 'chicken_two', 'apple_two']
data = [random.choice(events) for __ in range(10)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['event'])

regex_dict = {
        'apples': 'apple',
        'chickens': 'chicken',
        'ones': 'one',
        'twos': 'two',
}

lambda_dict = {
    col:
    lambda x, regex=regex: (
        x['event']
        .str.contains(regex)
        .astype(int)
    )
    for col, regex in regex_dict.items()
}

res = df.assign(**lambda_dict)
print(res)

# Output
         event  apples  chickens  ones  twos
0    apple_two       1         0     0     1
1    apple_two       1         0     0     1
2    apple_one       1         0     1     0
3  chicken_two       0         1     0     1
4    apple_two       1         0     0     1
5    apple_two       1         0     0     1
6  chicken_two       0         1     0     1
7    apple_two       1         0     0     1
8  chicken_two       0         1     0     1
9  chicken_one       0         1     1     0
```

The problem with the prior code was that the regex was only evaluated during the last loop. Adding it as a default argument fixes this.

Comment: Thank you @adrianp but I think something is wrong cause the output is not correct.

Comment: I edited the answer. Can you see if this is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

This can do what you want to do

```
pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame({a:list(df["event"].str.contains(b)) for a,b in Dic.items()})],axis=1)
```

Actually using a for loop will do the same

Comment: Thank you @Luk. Can you help me with assign method?

Comment: @mGolzadh   I found out that it is difficult to do it with assign,  although the documentation state that we can surely do something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/58244022/10189759 ,   however I think that there is a bug in implementing it.       Also, if you try to use for loop,  the variable in each loop failed to reference what it should. The function simply use the name of the loop variable to be the column name

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you question correctly, you're trying to rename the columns, in which case I think you could just use Pandas [rename function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html). This would look like

`df_res = df_res.rename(mapper=Dic)`

-Ben